# Orbot is able to open a circuit, but browser check still doesn't confirm using Tor

Tags: circuit, orbot

According to the Orbot Log the program was able to open a circuit. But if I run a browser check, it still tells me that I am not using tor. 
I also uses a bridge, but the result stays the same.

How can I ensure that I am using Tor?

Best regards,
Severin

Comment: The *bridges* have nothing to do with the *exit*, they're simply guards (entry point of a circuit). Check your proxy configuration and verify you're not only using Orbot, but also applying the Orbot proxy to your network configuration. (SOCKS 4A/5: 127.0.0.1:9050, HTTP: 127.0.0.1:8118)

Comment: After turning on Orbot, open the Orweb or the Orfox apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Orbot** you must be on an **Android** device. 
On an android device you can use the **duck duck go** search browser or **Orweb** browser as both of these are pre-configured to use Orbot and therefore the Tor system.
When you start **duck duck go** or **Orweb** browser if **Orbot** is not running it will ask you if you want to use **Orbot** and start it for you. both **Orbot** and **Duck Duck Go** can be found at the Google play store for free.
I hope this helps you [Severin](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/8042/severin)

Comment: It is now recommended to use Orfox instead of Orweb.

Answer (score 0):

Unless specifically configured to do so, Orbot does not connect an entire device to Tor so you have to configured which applications will use it. This is why they provide [OrWeb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.browser&hl=en) which is pre-configured to use Orbot. You can also use Firefox with a proxy configuration but you'll have to know how to do that.